# How can I install a .cls file with MikTeX?

Tags: installing, miktex, document-classes, texmf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

I am new to LaTeX, but need to write up a report pretty soon. Anyway, the instruction for authors state that I should include this line:

```
\documentclass{svmult}
```

Okay, easy enough, I have the `svmult.cls` file. However, where do I include this? I tried putting in the same directory as other `.cls` files and even in the same folder where my project exists. However, no luck. I do have a bunch of other files:

[image]

Not really sure what to do with these though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For an overwiew, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files. This also works for `.cls` files.

Comment: For an answer more specifically aimed at MikTeX, see also this question: [How do I manually install a package on MikTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/2693).